# What is the way to create/export x,y,z coordinates of roads from a shp file in QGIS?

Tags: csv, export, coordinates, shapefile, qgis

## What is the way to create/export x,y,z coordinates of roads from a shp file in QGIS ?

In my specific case, I have tried with the swiss road network, by taking the following steps:

### Step 1

Download

> swisstlm3d_2022-03_2056_5728.shp.zip

from
https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/geodata/landscape/tlm3d.html

### Step 2

In QGIS go to Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Layer

and adding the following file as Source / Vector Dataset:

> swissTLM3D_TLM_STRASSE.shp

### Step 3

Once the file is loaded, go to the just added layer , click the right button of the mouse, and then go to

Export > Save Features As

and use the following options:

- Format: Comma Separated Value (CSV)
- Geometry: As_XYZ
- Separator: Comma

### Step 4

With Excel open the just created CSV file. It contains the following fields, **but not the x,y,z coordinates of the roads endpoints, nor the intermediary points forming the polylines of the roads**....

> UUID  DATUM_AEND  DATUM_ERST  ERSTELL_J   ERSTELL_M   REVISION_J  REVISION_M  GRUND_AEND  HERKUNFT    HERKUNFT_J  HERKUNFT_M  OBJEKTART   REVISION_Q  KUNSTBAUTE  WANDERWEGE  BEFAHRBARK  EROEFFNUNG  STUFE   RICHTUNGSG  STR_NAME_U  NAME    BELAGSART   KREISEL VERKEHRSBE  EIGENTUEME  VERKEHRSBD  STRNAME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Extract Vertices tool (QGIS Version 3.20.2).  This may be called Extract Nodes in previous versions.

Once you have the output from the nodes, you can use Add Coordinates to Points to get the X, Y, and Z values.

[image]

The attributes from the original line data will be carried through to the vertices, which means you could join the data back to the original line file although this would be a 1:M join resulting in a lot of rows - one row per vertex.

Extract the data using the same method as before.